# HDF to HDP data store

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

We have two clusters. One is HDF cluster including Nifi and the other one is HDP cluster included hdf, Hive other components. We are reading data from file and want to place in hdp cluster hdfs.

Can anybody point out to documentation regarding this or some examples..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

NiFi's [PutHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html) processor will write data to HDFS.  You configure it with your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files.

Sometimes network, security, or application configurations make it difficult to securely write files from a remote NiFi to a Hadoop cluster.  A common pattern is to use two NiFis - one NiFi collects, formats, and aggregates records before transmitting to a second NiFi inside the Hadoop cluster via NiFi [site-to-site](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#site-to-site) protocol.  Because the second NiFi is inside the Hadoop cluster, it can make it easier to write files securely to HDFS.

PutHDFS features in a couple NiFi [Example Dataflow Templates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Example+Dataflow+Templates), which also demonstrate commonly related activities like aggregating data, directory and file naming, and NiFi site-to-site communication.

Comment: Thanks James.. for now i have n't faced any network related issues.